# Hector_SLAM on BeagleBone error

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, beaglebone, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have hector_slam running on the BeagleBone. IMU_UM6 and URG-04X both launch and stream data.

I have not had success getting hokuyo_node functional so I am using the newer urg_node and changed the launch file for hector_slam to launch the urg_node rather than the hokuyo_node.

I do not have rviz running on the BeagleBone as there is no display attached to the BeagleBone.

When I launch hector_slam I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1370640753.966993122]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_stabilized failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (4):
Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent /base_stabilized.
Frame /base_stabilized exists with parent NO_PARENT.
```

Is this because rviz is not running and loading the map, or do I have a different issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64569/hector_slam-on-beaglebone-error/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's just a startup artifact due to tf not being fully up and running, as the order of node startup in a launch file is pretty much random. Will look into suppressing this error at a later date :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0